# Stacking decorators in Python

Tags: python, decorator

So...

This works

```
def makeBold(fn):
    def wrapped():
        return '<b>'+fn()+'</b>'
    return wrapped
@makeBold
def sayhello():
    return 'Ey yo wassup'
```

and produces an expected **Ey yo wassup**

However, this does not work

```
def makeBold(fn):
    def wrapped():
        return '<b>'+fn()+'</b>'
    return wrapped

def makeItalic(fn):
    def wrapped():
        return '<i>'+fn()+'</i>'

@makeItalic
@makeBold
def sayhello():
    return 'Ey yo wassup'
```

Which all produces this nice NoneType error...

I thought it would produce something like ***Ey yo wassup***

Thoughts?

Comment: You forgot to return `wrapped` from `makeItalic`.

Comment: In case the tag order ever mattered to you, decorators are applied inner to outer, so the above would return `<i><b>Ey yo wassup</b></i>`

Comment: Good note, I noticed this after I fixed it.  Thanks Pavel!

Answer (score 0):

```
def makeBold(fn):
    def wrapped():
        return '<b>'+fn()+'</b>'
    return wrapped

def makeItalic(fn):
    def wrapped():
        return '<i>'+fn()+'</i>'
    return wrapped

@makeItalic
@makeBold
def sayhello():
    return 'Ey yo wassup'
```